# Where can I find a PL/I Compiler for Windows?

Tags: pl-i

50 years ago, I worked for IBM in a mainframe-environment and was an absolute fan of PL/I, this powerful and flexible language. Today I'm retired and would like to program in this language again.

I'm searching for a PL/I-Compiler for my Windows 10 machine.
Where can I find one? Do you know a free software? Or how much would it cost?

Comment: I just discover this site today as I am looking for PL/1 use with Linux.
I am 70 and a former PL/1 user during 15 years.
I have developed lot of sytem applications as I worked in a major american grain company.
I will be glad to exchange with people who really liked this language. I found a PL/1 compiler for both OS/2 an Linux here : http://www.iron-spring.com/download.html Hope it will help as this topic is open since a long time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm happy to hear of your fondness for PL/I! IBM no longer has a PL/I product for Windows (we have PL/I compilers that run on AIX and on z/OS). Microfocus may still sell a PL/I compiler for Windows.

Comment: http://pl1gcc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @cobp That project was a sorry sight :D Last commit in 2007 for version 0.15 that could just do one level deep nesting. I think one should look elsewhere :D

Comment: yes i didnt check that, seems to be quite old. but the Open cobol compiler seems to be pretty stable many using it. My ex employer switched from IBM compiler to Open cobol in linux and windows. Micro-focus pl1 is still active and our shop uses it (Batch processing for a major international finance organization).

Answer (score 1):

You may use ibm360 emulators like Music, or Hercules, where you run 360/370 even 390 Emulations where you can run the original IMB PL/I(F) Tapes ( getit at CBTAPES).
There's a very good PL/I made by Digital research, you can run in CPM on MYz80 or YAZE emulators. Theres even a free version of an OS/2, and LInux by Iron Spring.
Yesterday night I compiled some stuff I did in the 80's using Digital Research PL/I on a CPM emulator environment.

I loved this language, since I was at the engineering school, and did my thesis on making a cross compiler, with PL/I. Then I moved to C and C++, which I find very similar to